# Range producing runtime error 1004 when changed to cells

Tags: excel, vba, range, runtime-error

The part below started to produce runtime error 1004 when I changed the range from letters to cells:

With letters:

```
Application.SumIf(Sheets(4).Range("E:P"), _
Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
Sheets(4).Range("K:K"))
```

Without letters:

```
Application.SumIf( _ 
    Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(intLstRowA, 16)), _
    Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
    Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(intLstRowA, 11)))
```

It is part of a larger loop:

```
intLstRowA = Sheets(4).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To 9
    Sheets(6).Cells(i, 2) = _
        Format( _
            Application.SumIf( _
                Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(intLstRowA, 16)), _
                Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
                Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(intLstRowA, 11))) _ 
                / _
            Application.SumIf(Sheets(4).Range("E:P"), _
                Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
                Sheets(4).Range("P:P")) * 0.01, _
           "Percent")
Next i
```

I never use .Select, .Active etc. and I cannot figure out what is causing the error. Can you help me sanity check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because you aren't properly qualifying your `Cells` property calls. If you don't qualify, it will assume you're referring to the currently active sheet.

```
Application.SumIf( _ 
    Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(intLstRowA, 16)), _
    Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
    Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(intLstRowA, 11)))
'                   ^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

On what sheet are these cells? Say so explicitly:

```
'                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
Application.SumIf( _ 
    Sheets(4).Range(Sheets(4).Cells(1, 5), Sheets(4).Cells(intLstRowA, 16)), _
    Sheets(6).Cells(i, 1).Value2, _
    Sheets(4).Range(Sheets(4).Cells(1, 11), Sheets(4).Cells(intLstRowA, 11)))
'                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The former case will give you an error if a different sheet than `Sheet(4)` happens to be active, because it would be looking to define a range in one sheet whose corners are defined by cells on another sheet — clearly nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

`Sheets(4).Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(intLstRowA, 16))` will only work if `Sheets(4)` is the `ActiveSheet`.

This is because `Cells(1,5)` is not saying whose cells are meant. So the ActiveSheet's cells are believed.

`Sheets(4).Range(Sheets(4).Cells(1, 5), Sheets(4).Cells(intLstRowA, 16))` will work.

But better you are working with `With`:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(4)
...
... .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(intLstRowA, 16))...
...
End With
```

Comment: JFC replied a tad earlier, so I marked his answer as the reply. Thanks again and also for the With suggestion, there would be quite a lot of Sheets(4). to add without it!